# How do I change a Netgear R8000P default router IP address without losing access to the router?

Tags: networking, router, ip

I have traditionally had a router at the IP 192.168.0.1 which is a) easy for me to remember and b) has allowed me to have static IPs for devices running in the x.x.0.x range (192.168.0.5, 192.168.0.100, etc.)

My new router, a Netgear Nighthawk R8000P, uses a default of 192.168.1.1, and a mask of 255.255.255.0 -- which means that I'm only able to assign static IPs in the range of x.x.1.x.

I had hoped to change the default IP of the router by simply editing its configuration to 192.168.0.1 but the moment I did this and "applied" the change and rebooted the router, I lost all contact.  I couldn't access it on 192.168.0.1 NOR on the previous 192.168.1.1.  I should add that I was not accessing the router via the app because I didn't want yet another damn app on my phone, but was using a wired connection to access the router through a desktop PC (Lubuntu 20.04LTS, if it matters).

Long story short is that I had to reset the router to factory default and (currently) have everything set via the default, 192.168.1.1.  And things work now, but I'm wondering what went so horribly wrong earlier and whether I can change that back, as I have a number of scripts that use the x.x.0.x setup that I'm a bit loathe to change.

Lastly, do I run any security risks in leaving it at the default IP?  I thought that changing from the default was always a good idea.  Does it matter much?

Comment: “Lastly, do I run any security risks in leaving it at the default IP?” - No; Changing the setting the way you did should have worked.  If you want assistance, provide screenshots of what you changed, so we can verify you changed everything that should have been changed.  Intranet settings are not unique so submitting the actual values you used are important if you want help.

Comment: When you accessed the Nighthawk first time, you must have used IP address in `192.168.1.x`, you wouldn't be able to connect with `192.168.0.x`-address. After you changed the IP of the router to `192.168.0.1`, did you change the IP of the system to `192.168.0.x`? If not, you again wouldn't be able to connect. Before changing the router IP, did you remove the old router from the network? If not, you had an IP address conflict, and again no access.

Comment: That should have worked. I wonder if yhe issue is that you changed yhe IP on the router but not your PC.  One partial solution might be to change the netmask from 255.255.255.0 to 155.255.0.0, which will allow devices to have a 192.188.0 or 192.168.1 address. (The problem is you will still need go change the gateway unless you update the routers gateway)

Answer (score 0):

> I thought that changing from the default was always a good idea. Does
> it matter much?

I always change the default range to an uncommon range, in part, so as to facilitate VPN connections.

Now you first have to change the LAN IP and LAN IP Subnet Mask. Stay in this screen.

Second, make the DHCP range you need. LAN IP normally cannot be changed in the DHCP setup.

Third, save the config, and restart the router.  If the computer does not see the new IP right away, restart it as well.  If necessary, do a TCP/IP Reset on the computer.

> Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
>
> (1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
>
> (2) ipconfig /flushdns
>
> (3) restart the computer

Now connect on the new LAN IP.

This always works for me.

You can always factory reset and try again.

Screen shot of the main settings and order to set follows (not a Netgear Router)

[image: Router LAN Setup]

Answer (score 0):

What you did was enough. You should have rebooted the computer for it to
be allocated a new IP address by the router, not rebooted the router.

The only possible problem is if you have assigned your computer a *static*
IP address in the range of `192.168.1.x`, so that communication with
the router became impossible when its allocation range changed to
`192.168.0.x`.

Another possible problem is if you have setup the router to give your
computer a specific IP address in the range of `192.168.1.x`,
so that it continued on giving the computer an IP that after the change
wasn't part of the local network any more.
Such a setting would be erased by a factory reset of the router.

Comment: This seems very much like what I did wrong.  I probably had an IP address set by the router initially that was in the 192.168.1.x range, then I changed the router's range to 192.168.0.x and after that, it wouldn't connect...but I didn't restart the computer.  I suspect that was what I should have done, so that the router would have reset my computer's IP to something in the 192.168.0.x range.  Thank you.  I will try that!